# How to call a notification/toast after a server action in Nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ecmascript-6, next.js13

Hi I am struggling to find out how to call a toast after a successful data mutation using server actions in Nextjs 13. The toast is a client component since it uses a hook/context.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: how about you share some code first?

Comment: @Yilmaz There isn’t really any code for me to share. I was reading the documentation but didnt see anywhere how to go about doing that.

Comment: Share the document u are reading

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this result using the `useFormStatus()` hook.

Suppose you have a form component that uses a Server Action. Here's a basic Server Component that might invoke your server action, defined in another file:

```js
import { submit } from "./serverAction";

export function ServerForm() {
  return (
    <form action={submit}>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

To manage data returned by the server action and, for instance, display errors adjacent to each input, you'd need to convert this form into a Client Component:

```js
"use client"

import { submit } from "./serverAction";
// @ts-ignore: Experimental feature not yet in react-dom type definitions
import { experimental_useFormState as useFormState } from "react-dom";

export function ClientForm() {
  // You pass your ServerAction and an initial state to `useFormState`
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(submit, {
    error: { name: null, email: null },
    message: null,
  });

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <p>{state?.error?.email}</p>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <p>{state?.error?.name}</p>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

In this context, I'm returning an object from my ServerAction:

```js
"use server";

export async function submit(formData: FormData) {
  // Extract data from the submitted form
  const name = formData.get("name") as string;
  const email = formData.get("email") as string;

  try {
    // You might do data validation and database interactions here
    // On success, you'd probably redirect instead of returning an object
    return { error: null, message: `New submission: ${name} - ${email}` };
  } catch (e) {
    // Error handling
    return {
      error: {
        name: "There was an error with this name",
        email: "There was an error with this email",
      },
      message: "Failed submission",
    };
  }
}
```

You can seamlessly trigger a Toaster by setting a `useEffect` that observes `state`. For instance, using the [toaster from shadcn](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/toast):

```js
"use client";

import { useToast } from "@components/shadcn-ui-registry/use-toast";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { submit } from "./serverAction";
// @ts-ignore: Experimental feature not yet in react-dom type definitions
import { experimental_useFormState as useFormState } from "react-dom";

export function ClientForm() {
  // You pass your ServerAction and an initial state to `useFormState`
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(submit, {
    error: { name: null, email: null },
    message: null,
  });

  const { toast } = useToast();
  useEffect(() => {
    toast({
      title: state?.error?.name || state?.error?.email ? "Error" : "Success",
      description: state.message,
    });
  }, [state, toast]);

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <p>{state?.error?.email}</p>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <p>{state?.error?.name}</p>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

For more details, refer to the [Next.js documentation for forms and mutations](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations). Hope this helped, feel free to give feedback or ask anything that was unclear.

Comment: You could probably also do something like:

`<form action={(data) => submit(data).then((res) => {
    toast({ title: "", description: res.message})
})}>`

Comment: the solution in the comment doesn't work when you want to use the state to display errors in the form. Overall i wish they gave a cannonical situation to this since this approach although it works feels like a lot of work for a single toast

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, there is no canonical way to do this.
There are workarounds. Those could be different depending on if you are rendering a server or a client component, although they could be related.

- Option one: Set a cookie on the server action and read it on the next request (when the user is being redirected back to the page). You could set the cookie with a short expire time. You could put whatever you want in the cookie and render your toast based on it.
- Option two: Create a global state on the server and put whatever you want in it. You should identify the state you'll set with the identity of the request, otherwise you could be showing toasts to the wrong user.
- Option three: Use some kind of session manager and put the toast message on the session. Depending on the type of session you'll manage, this could be inside the header, the cookies, in memory, etc.

Honestly, it sucks that next doesn't offer a solution for this out of the box and leaves user to come up with whatever they can think of, including possible bad solutions.

See the cookie example:

```js
// Server action file
"use server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
...

// At the end of your server action function:
cookies()
  .set(
    "my-app-toast-msg",
    JSON.stringify({error: true, msg: "wrong credentials"}, {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000), // 10 seconds
    })
  );
```

```js
// At your server component file
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function Page() {
  const toastMsg = cookies().get("my-app-toast-msg");

  return (
    <>
      {!!toastMsg &&
        JSON.parse(toastMsg).error &&
        <ClientErrorToast errorMsg={JSON.parse(toastMsg).msg} />
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

This is a quick a dirty, non tested implementation from memory and I don't know if it's a good solution.
I use an error as an example but you should be able to see the idea.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I have made a little library to handle this, working with nextjs and shadcn, coming from SvelteKit where there is the flash-message library https://github.com/ciscoheat/sveltekit-flash-message

Put this in your lib/flash-toaster

**flash-toaster.tsx**

```
import { Toaster } from '@/components/ui/sonner';
import FlashToasterClient from '@/lib/flash-toaster/flash-toaster-client';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export function FlashToaster() {
  const flash = cookies().get('flash');
  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />
      <FlashToasterClient flash={flash?.value} />
    </>
  );
}

export function setFlash(flash: { type: 'success' | 'error'; message: string }) {
  cookies().set('flash', JSON.stringify(flash), { path: '/', expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000) });
}
```

**flash-toaster-client.tsx**

```
'use client';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'sonner';

export default function FlashToasterClient(props: { flash: string | undefined }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!props.flash) {
      const { type, message } = JSON.parse(props.flash);
      if (type === 'success') {
        toast.success(message);
      } else if (type === 'error') {
        toast.error(message);
      }
    }
  }, [props.flash]);
  return null;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { FlashToaster, setFlash } from './flash-toaster';
export { FlashToaster, setFlash };
```

Then in your layout.tsx (where you would put your `<Toaster/>` component) use the `<FlashToaster />` like this

**app/layout.tsx**

```
import { FlashToaster } from '@/lib/flash-toaster';
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <main>{children}</main>
        <FlashToaster />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And in your actions you can call the `setFlash` function to add messages that will persist across redirects

**action.ts**

```
export function createUser() {
  ... create the user ...

  setFlash({ type: 'success', message: 'User create successfully' });
  redirect(`/users`);
}
```