# How to show toasts in react server components?

Tags: next.js, toast, react-server-components

I'm using Next.js 14 with the app router.

I have two server components:

1. List page `/products` that shows multiple products
2. Product Details page `/products/{id}`.

On `/products/{id}` I check whether the `id` is available in my products database with a server action and then render the product.

If the product is not available, I wanted to redirect the user back to `/products` and show a toast message that the product was not found.

Redirecting is simple enough:

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

async function getNoProduct() {
  return null
}

export default async function RedirectFromPage() {
  
  let res = await getNoProduct()
  if (!res === null) {
    redirect('/products')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello SO</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, I'm stuck implementing the toast message (using sonner toast via [shadcn](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/sonner)).

Directly adding the toast like below doesn't work because `/products/{id}` is a server component and toast relies on useEffect,
e.g.

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast'

async function getNoProduct() {
  return null
}

export default async function RedirectFromPage() {
  const { toast } = useToast()

  let res = await getNoProduct()
  if (!res === null) {
    // Show toast
    toast({
      title: 'Error',
      description: 'Product not found',
    })
    redirect('/products')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello SO</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

will result in an error `Error: useState only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-client-hook-in-server-component`

Based on another SO question related to server actions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393897/how-to-call-a-notification-toast-after-a-server-action-in-nextjs13)) I thought I could use cookies to communicate the error to `/products` and then render a client component that uses the toast but ran into issues because I can [trigger these server actions only from a client component](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51875#issuecomment-1667994091).

How should I approach this? Is toast just the wrong type of component here or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To me this seems more like an UI question than a coding question, perhaps more suitable for [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) rather than here. A coding question may be more appropriate once you've settled for the desired behavior.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks, I tried re-phrasing the question, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is the toast packages are meant for client side. For server side, I think you can create a loading.tsx page and nextjs will show the loading page then the intended page. If it’s a client side component inside a server rendered page, you should be able to use React Suspense to wrap the client side component in your server rendered page